# Why is my modal height taking up half of the screen?

Tags: react-native

My modal -- noDevicesModalContainer -- is taking up an enormous amount of the screen and I can't work out why.

I am very new to React Native and web development generally, so please do not be afraid to overexplain!

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

```
class DevicesEmptyScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <View style={styles.noDevicesImage}>
          <Image
            source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/no_devices.png')}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.noDevicesTextContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.noDevicesText}>You do not have any devices yet</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.noDevicesModalContainer}>
          <Text style={[styles.noDevicesText, styles.noDevicesModalText]}>
            In case no devices have been assigned, please contact your administrator
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default DevicesEmptyScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  noDevicesImage: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 40
  },
  noDevicesTextContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  noDevicesText: {
    color: '#89C7C8',
    padding: 10
  },
  noDevicesModalContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#EBF5F6',
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 30,
    marginVertical: 30
  },
  noDevicesModalText: {
    marginLeft: 20
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the result, and explain what are you expecting the modal to be pls ?

Comment: where is your screen when use modal?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) documentation. Try this

```
<Modal transparent={true}
       visible={this.state.isVisible}
       onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>
  <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 300}}>
      ...
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```